# Get the value with most occurrences in data frame for each row

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

Suppose I have a simple data frame

```
test_df <- data.frame(c(0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1),c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
```

I want to get which number (0 or 1) is the maximum for each row. 
In my example 1 for the first vector (6 occurrences), 0 for the second one (9 occurrences).

I started with:

```
> sapply(test_df,table)
  c.0..0..1..0..0..1..1..1..1..1. c.1..0..0..0..0..0..0..0..0..0.
0                               4                               9
1                               6                               1
```

so far looks fine. Then

```
> sapply((sapply(test_df,table)),max)
[1] 4 6 9 1
```

I got lost, did I loose the associations? 1 -> 6 , 0 -> 9
What I want is to have returned a vector with the "winner": 1,0,...

```
1 for the first vector (6 occurrences)
0 for the second vector (9 occurrences)
...
```

Comment: When you are creating a `data.frame` without any column names, you will get the `c.0..0..1..0..0..1..1..1..1..1` as column names.  Please check the output of 'test_df' you created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in one `apply` statement. Although, it's unclear whether you want the maximum occurrences for each row or column, so here's both (using @akrun 's cleaner data set), returning a vector showing the 'winner' (either 1 or 0) for each row/column.

```
## Data
test_df <- data.frame(v1= c(0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1),
                      v2= c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                      v3= c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)) 
#    v1 v2 v3
# 1   0  1  1
# 2   0  0  0
# 3   1  0  0
# 4   0  0  0
# 5   0  0  0
# 6   1  0  0
# 7   1  0  0
# 8   1  0  0
# 9   1  0  0
# 10  1  0  1

## Solution - For each row
apply(test_df, 1, function(x) { sum(sum(x == 1) > sum(x == 0)) })

## Result
# [1] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1

## Solution - For each column
apply(test_df, 2, function(x) { sum(sum(x == 1) > sum(x == 0)) })

## Result 
# v1 v2 v3 
# 1  0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN=1` to extract the `max` value from each row of the `sapply` output.

```
frqCol <- sapply(test_df, table)
apply(frqCol, 1, max)
# 0 1 
# 9 6
```

or use `rowMaxs` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
rowMaxs(frqCol)
#[1] 9 6
```

If we need the 'max' value per column

```
apply(frqCol, 2, max)
```

and

```
colMaxs(frqCol)
```

With the new example

```
test_df <- data.frame(v1= c(0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1),
                  v2= c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                  v3= c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)) 
frqCol <- sapply(test_df, table)
apply(frqCol, 2, max)
#v1 v2 v3 
#6  9  8 
colMaxs(frqCol)
#[1] 6 9 8
```

Comment: sapply + apply looks pretty close, but how to use apply if I add another vector to the data frame? `test_df <- data.frame(c(0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1),c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1))`

Comment: @user869097  Can you please update this in your post.  It is so hard to copy/paste from the comments.  Also please do update the expected output

Comment: @user869097  Updated the post

Comment: what about a pretty inefficient: `do.call(pmax, data.frame(t(frqCol)))` ;)

Comment: @G.Cocca  Yes, it can be used, but we need to convert it to data.frame.